# setting a static variable in java

Tags: java

I am new to java hence probably a very noob question:

I have a class

```
public class Foo{
  private static String foo;
  private String bar;

  public Foo(String bar){
      this.bar = bar;
  }

}
```

Now before I instantiate any object for class Foo, I want to set that static variable foo.
which will be used in the class..
How do i do this?

Also, please correct my understanding. value of foo will be same across all the objects, hence it does make sense to declare it as static ? right?

Comment: Just write `private static String foo = "MyValue";`  Will it differ depending on run-time decisions?

Comment: You want it to be set to a constant value? Or to change its value sometimes? Is a null value acceptable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public class Foo{
  private static String foo = "initial value";
  private String bar;

  public Foo(String bar){
      this.bar = bar;
  }

}
```

Since the value will be the same across all objects, `static` is the right thing to use.  If the value is not only `static` but also never changing, then you should do this instead:

```
public class Foo{
  private static final String FOO = "initial value";
  private String bar;

  public Foo(String bar){
      this.bar = bar;
  }

}
```

Notice how the capitalization changed there?  That's the java convention.  "Constants" are NAMED_LIKE_THIS.

Answer (score 5):

1. `foo` will be shared among all instances of `Foo`
2. To initialize it:

**Option A**

`private static String foo = "static variable";`

**Option B**

```
private static String foo;

static {
    foo = "static variable";
}
```

Option B is seldom used, mostly when there are some inter-dependencies between static variables or potential exceptions.

In either case, static init will happen when the class is loaded.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by the other answers, you should set your initial value like so:

```
private static String foo = "initial value";
```

Additionally, if you want to access this variable from anywhere, you need to reference it in a static context, like so:

```
Foo.foo
```

where `Foo` is the class name, and `foo` is the variable name.

This is actually very useful in understanding the concept of static variables. Rather than referencing `foo` as a member of some *instance* of the `Foo` class, you are referencing `foo` as a member of the class itself. So, for all instances of `Foo`, the value of `foo` will be the same because it is owned by the **class** and not the **instance**.

Inside the `Foo` class, you can get away with just calling `foo` without qualifying it with a class name.